Is there a way to make Nuget update all packages while respecting the most restrictive version constraints?
I have a Sitefinity web app in Visual Studio that, via Nuget, I am trying to update as much as possible without moving to a new Sitefinity version.
In packages.config, I restrict all Sitefinity packages to version 13 like so:
<package id="Telerik.Sitefinity.All" version="13.3.7649" targetFramework="net48" allowedVersions="(,14.0)" />

This stops Nuget from trying to update Sitefinity, but still gives "Unable to resolve dependencies" errors when it tries to update Sitefinity's dependencies.
Other than adding allowedVersions constraints to every transitory dependency, is there a way to make Nuget compute all the constraints, and only update packages to the limit of those constraints?

To explain in more detail: Nuget package     Progress.Sitefinity.Core.13.3.7649 has these dependencies:
Telerik.DataAccess.Core [2020.0.428.1]
Telerik.DataAccess.Web35 [2020.0.428.1]
Progress.Sitefinity.Renderer [13.3.7626.24196]
ServiceStack [5.9.2]
ServiceStack.Redis [5.9.2]
ServiceStack.Server [5.9.2]
ServiceStack.Aws [5.9.2]
ServiceStack.Caching.Memcached [5.9.2]
ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer [5.9.2]
AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 3.5.2
AWSSDK.SQS 3.5.0.36
Telerik.Web.UI [2021.1.119.45]
Newtonsoft.Json [12.0.3]

If I tell nuget to update all packages, it tries to update, eg, ServiceStack to the latest version (currently 8.0), then throws an error because of the Sitefinity version constraint.

If you set <package id="Telerik.Sitefinity.All" version="13.3.7649" targetFramework="net48" allowedVersions="(13,14)" /, will nuget update the packages while respecting constraints?

I did a quick test on Newtonsoft.Json(Looks like Telerik.Sitefinity.All is not availle in Nuget Gallery) by adding allowedVersions and found it can make Nuget update all packages while respecting the most restrictive version constraints. Please check the following steps:
1.In my case, i restrict Newtonsoft.Json all packages to version 12 like this:
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.1" targetFramework="net472" allowedVersions="(,13.0)" />

2 Install 12.0.1 version.
nuget install packages.config

3 Update the package to latest version that up below 13 on update.
nuget update packages.config


Note:
allowedVersions="(,13.0)" 

However, this form is not recommended because it can be difficult to determine the lowest version. I would suggest you use this format
Install/restore version 13.3.7649, accept any 13.x version during update.
<package id="Telerik.Sitefinity.All" version="13.3.7649" targetFramework="net48" allowedVersions="(13,14)" /

By the way, if you use PackageReference, you can consider using Floating Versions to achieve it.

The problem is, updating packages that those packages have as dependencies. It tries to update those to their latest versions, then gives an error due to the version constraint.

Yes, i can reproduce the issue, it throws an error "one or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected xxx". This issue is similar to the first and the second. Please check if them help.
